# Looking for a cleaner way to scrape from website by avoiding repeating

Tags: ruby

Hi I am just doing a bit of refactoring on a small cli web scraping project I did in Ruby and I was simply wondering if there was cleaner way to write a particular section without repeating the code too much.

Basically with the code below, I pulled data from a website but I had to do this per page. You will notice that both methods are only different by their name and the source.

```
 def self.scrape_first_page
        
        html = open("https://www.texasblackpages.com/united-states/san-antonio")
        doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
        doc.css('div.grid_element').each do |business|    
            biz = Business.new
            biz.name = business.css('a b').text
            biz.type = business.css('span.hidden-xs').text
            biz.number = business.css('span.sm-block.lmargin.sm-nomargin').text.gsub("\r\n","").strip
            
            
        end 
        
    end

    def self.scrape_second_page
        
        html = open('https://www.texasblackpages.com/united-states/san-antonio?page=2')
        doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
        doc.css('div.grid_element').each do |business|    
            biz = Business.new
            biz.name = business.css('a b').text
            biz.type = business.css('span.hidden-xs').text
            biz.number = business.css('span.sm-block.lmargin.sm-nomargin').text.gsub("\r\n","").strip
        end  
    end
```

Is there a way for me to streamline this process all with just one method pulling from one source, but have the ability to access different pages within the same site, or this is pretty much the best and only way? They owners of the website do not have a public api from me to pull from in case anyone is wondering.

Comment: Take the url as a method argument.

Comment: This actually made it a little better as I have less methods to deal with. Without there being a public api available I had to invoke the same method a few times, but nonetheless it reduced some code in the class file I have them. Thanks @ToddA.Jacobs

Comment: This is the backbone of the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that in programming you want to steer towards code that follows the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) avoid the dreaded *two*. In other words, write methods that take no arguments, fixed arguments (one), or an array of unspecified size (infinity).

So the first step is to clean up the scraping function to make it as generic as possible:

```rb
def scrape(page)
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(page))

  # Use map here to return an array of Business objects
  doc.css('div.grid_element').map do |business|
    Business.new.tap do |biz|
      # Use tap to modify this object before returning it
      biz.name = business.css('a b').text
      biz.type = business.css('span.hidden-xs').text
      biz.number = business.css('span.sm-block.lmargin.sm-nomargin').text.gsub("\r\n","").strip
    end
  end
end
```

Note that apart from the extraction code, there's nothing specific about this. Takes a URL, returns `Business` objects in an `Array`.

In order to generate pages 1..N, consider this:

```rb
def pages(base_url, start: 1)
  page = start

  Enumerator.new do |y|
    loop do
      y << base_url % page

      page += 1
    end
  end
end
```

Now that's an infinite series, but you can always cap it to whatever you want with `take(n)` or by instead looping until you get an empty list:

```rb
# Collect all business from each of the pages...
businesses = pages('https://www.texasblackpages.com/united-states/san-antonio?page=%d').lazy.map do |page|
  # ...by scraping the page...
  scrape(page)
end.take_while do |results|
  # ...and iterating until there's no results, as in Array#any? is false.
  results.any?
end.to_a.flatten
```

The `.lazy` part means "evaluate each part of the chain sequentially" as opposed to the default behaviour of trying to evaluate each stage to completion. This is important or else it will try and download an infinite number of pages before moving to the next test.

The `.to_a` on the end forces that chain to run to completion. The `.flatten` squishes all the page-wise results into a single result set.

Of course if you want to scrape the first N pages, it's a lot easier:

```rb
pages('https://www.texasblackpages.com/.../san-antonio?page=%d').take(n).flat_map do |page|
  scrape(page)
end
```

It's almost no code!

Comment: This actually gives me a better break down, and definitely looks more efficient in regards to performance.

Answer (score 0):

This was suggested by @Todd A. Jacobs

```
def self.scrape(url)
        
        html = open(url)
        
        doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
        doc.css('div.grid_element').each do |business|    
            biz = Business.new
            biz.name = business.css('a b').text
            biz.type = business.css('span.hidden-xs').text
            biz.number = business.css('span.sm-block.lmargin.sm-nomargin').text.gsub("\r\n","").strip
            
            
end
```

The downside is with there not being a public api I had to invoke the method as many times as I need it since the url's are representing  different pages within the wbesite, but this is fine because I was able to get rid of the repeating methods.

```
 def make_listings
       
        Scraper.scrape("https://www.texasblackpages.com/united-states/san-antonio")
        Scraper.scrape("https://www.texasblackpages.com/united-states/san-antonio?page=2")
        Scraper.scrape("https://www.texasblackpages.com/united-states/san-antonio?page=3")
        Scraper.scrape("https://www.texasblackpages.com/united-states/san-antonio?page=4")
    end
```

Comment: Loops please. This is an even bigger mess than previously.

Answer (score 0):

i ever had some problem with you, i do loop though. usually if the page support pagination then the first page it have chance to use query param page also.

```ruby
def self.scrape
 page = 1
 loop do
  url = "https://www.texasblackpages.com/united-states/san-antonio?page=#{page}"
  # do nokogiri parse
  # do data scrapping
  page += 1
 end
end

you can have break on certain page condition.
```